# Login Error script in PHP and Mysqli

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

Ok i know this is the wrong way, i haven't implement salt and other small secure tips
but now i need to understand what is the problem here, then i can implement other secure functions to the script, thanks for help :)
When run this, the script return Login Error, i can understand why, i print the password $_POST['password'] and it is same on database but when try to print $col2  (the password get from database ) return nothing.
Here is the code:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "*******", "test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
/* prepare statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ss" , $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    /* bind variables to prepared statement */
    $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);
    $stmt->store_result();
    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);
    }

    if($col1 && $col2 == $username && $password){
    $_SESSION['Admin']; //test - not to be implemented
    session_start(); //Test - not to be implemented
    header("location index2.php");
    }else{echo "Login Error";} 
    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: `$col1 && $col2 == $username && $password` where do you saw this kind of syntax? In fact you haven't provided us info about $username and $password. Where do you get them from? Are $username nad $password the posted values? You are binding them, so it's from the user? How do you declare it?

Comment: When it comes to login script, then you should not try to create everything from scratch. There is so much that could go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($col1 && $col2 == $username && $password){
```

This statement checks if `$col1` is `TRUE` **and** `$col2 == $username` **and** `$password` is `TRUE`.

This condition will never be true and your script will always display that error message.

Consider the following example:

```
$username = $col1 = 'user';
$password = $col2 = 'pass';
var_dump($col1 && $col2 == $username && $password);
```

This returns `bool(false)`.

So, to fix the issue, you can change your code as follows:

```
if($col1 == $username && $col2 == $password) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`if($col1 && $col2 == $username && $password)` what is it? :)

In php it means that if `$col1` and `$col2` has any value other than zero and `$username` and `$password` have also values other than 0 then it's OK

you need create something like

`if($col1 == $username && $col2 == $password)`

if you keep md5 hashes in db use

`if($col1 == $username && $col2 == md5($password))`

or do it in mysql that has md5 function too.

I have noticed that you start session after `printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);` which will cause `headers already sent`.

`$_SESSION['Admin'];` this will cause also notice beacuse this variable is undefined

and another problem is with header() function. You can't print anything before this function cause it will also cause 'headers already sent'.

Answer (score 0):

Some obvious issues:

> session_start(); must precede any $_SESSION variables use
>
> header("location index2.php"); headers must be sent before any other stuff
>
> header("location index2.php"); no colon after location

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problems that other people have noted in their answers, you are also mixing  ***procedural*** mysqli statements and ***object-oriented*** mysqli statements.

Since you start by initializing a `new mysqli()`, you must follow the object oriented syntax.

Change `mysqli_connect_errno()` to `$mysqli->connect_errno`.